# Pyomo: a Set of a Set

Tags: python, set, pyomo

I'm new to Pyomo and Python. I was wondering if someone could help me with the case of a Set Q that is based on a Set P.

```
model.P = pyo.Set(initialize=list(df.iloc[:,0]))
model.Q = pyo.Set(model.P)
```

Model.P stands for the products I read in out of a file. Model.Q is the number of possible quantities for every product.
So, for example: product "AAA" has 3 different quantities, than I would like to set model.Q["AAA"] equal to the range(1,3). Product "BBB" has 7 different quantities, than I would like to set  model.Q["BBB"] equal to the range(1,7).

The number of quantities are read into a list [3, 7, ...]

When I want to initialize a parameter like the following, it gives an error like below the example.

```
# Setup time
model.st = pyo.Param(model.P,model.Q,initialize=setupTimes,domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

TypeError: Cannot apply a Set operator to an indexed Set component (Q)
```

How can I implement this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by a product having different quantities?  Is that similar to saying that there are a number of orders or such for varying quantities of a certain product, like saying product AAA is in 3 orders of varying quantity and the set is the orders?

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know what you intend to do with that set, but I feel there may be other ways to efficiently model your problem with just a set and a parameter of quantities for each set.

However, to do what you want, one way I suggest is to create a second set "model.PP" which has the range(max(list)) as elements.
Then you create a list of tuples mapping each of model.P to the elements of model.PP appropriately which you then use to initilise model.Q ie.

```
model.Q = pyo.Set(within=model.P*model.PP, initialise=[("AAA",1), ("AAA",2). . .])
```

You can create that new list with a for loop.

Comment: I succeeded in creating the set model.Q, but the problem of the "TypeError" remains. According to me the problem is that the set varies over model.P. For example the parameter model.st would be of the form [('AAA',1):10,('AAA',2):3,('BBB',1):6,('BBB',2):12,('BBB',3):2]. So, as you see for product 'AAA' it goes up to 2 for model.Q and for product 'BBB' it goes up to 3.

Comment: My bad! You need to include "within=" right after the open paranthesis and before the set declaration.